# What should I write in the DS-160 form for "primary work/education information", if I am a student but also work part time?

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I study in the university but also work part time at a private company. How should I answer this question?

Comment: Well, do you consider yourself a student who works on the side, or a worker who studies in his free time?

Comment: I am primarily a student, but there is no way to add the info of the company and I don't want to omit the info, as it may cause problems in the future

Comment: Even part-time jobs are a part of your work history so you need to mention in on the DS160. If you select student as your primary occupation can't you enter your current employer in one of the 'Present employer or school name' fields?

Comment: No, there is no way to do that. I can add them in the previous employers list but can't add the ending date in the future. Looks like I am just going to list my university and add my part time job in the past employers with ending date as today.

Comment: When you fill in previous employment, there's a free text field where you enter your duties. I would include that you're currently employed there.

Answer (score 1):

As you're primarily a student, you would indicate that in the question that asks for **Present Work/Education/Training Information**, selecting STUDENT as your primary occupation. You have the opportunity in *Briefly describe your duties* section to make mention of your part-time employment.

When you go on to **Previous Work/Education/Training Information** and add current (and any previous employers), you can show the date to present (e.g., when you're completing the form) and again note in *duties* that you are employed part time while in school.